# Code to delete outdated entries on a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this code on here which should work perfectly for me.  Was just hoping someone could change the code to delete entries that have dates that are 2 weeks old or older.  So if the script were to run today, it would delete any rows that are October 26th or older.

```
    function DeleteOldEntries() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MASTER");
var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array

var currentDate = new Date();//today

for (i=lastrow;i>=3;i--) {
var tempDate = values[i-1][2];// arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col3 = [2]
if ((tempDate!=NaN) && (tempDate <= currentDate))
{
  sheet.deleteRow(i);
}//closes if
}//closes for loop
}//closes function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Deleting Rows in a forEach loop

```
function DeleteOldEntries() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("MASTER");
  const sr = 3;//guessing data start on row 3
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let d = 0;//delete counter
  const dtv = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() - 15).valueOf();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let cdt = new Date(r[2]);//assume date is in column 3
    let cdtv = new Date(cdt.getFullYear(), cdt.getMonth(), cdt.getDate()).valueOf();
    if (cdtv < dtv) {
      sh.deleRow(i + sr - d++);
    }
  });
}
```

[Date.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From your script and question, you want to delete the rows when the date of column "C" is before 2 weeks from today.

In this case, how about the following modification? In your script, when the value of column "C" is the date object, you are comparing the date object.

#### From:

```
var currentDate = new Date();//today

for (i=lastrow;i>=3;i--) {
var tempDate = values[i-1][2];// arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col3 = [2]
if ((tempDate!=NaN) && (tempDate <= currentDate))
{
  sheet.deleteRow(i);
}//closes if
}//closes for loop
}//closes function
```

#### To:

```
  var currentDate = new Date();

  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 14); // Added: This means before 2 weeks from today.
  var d = currentDate.getTime(); // Added
  for (i = lastrow; i >= 3; i--) {
    var tempDate = values[i - 1][2];
    if ((tempDate != NaN) && (tempDate.getTime() <= d)) { // Modified
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)
- [setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)
- [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/7108653)